# Ubuntu as domain Controller and how to add ubuntu machine to that domain

Tags: 14.04, active-directory

Can we use Ubuntu as a Active directory domain controller and add an Ubuntu machine to that domain controller? If yes, how?
Ubuntu version 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-dc.html). It should do exactly what you want.